# Why doesn't the following array initialization work in Julia 1.0

Tags: arrays, size, julia, variable-declaration

I'm trying to plot a bunch of complex contours and attempted the following:

```
ax_matrix = Array{Union{Int,Float64},2}(length(iters),length(bx));
```

where `iters` and `bx` are 1-dimensional arrays. This gives me to following error:

```
LoadError: MethodError: no method matching Array{Union{Float64,Int64},2}(::Int64,::Int64)
Closest candidates are:
  Array{Union{Float64, Int64},2}(::UndefInitializer, ::Int64, ::Int64) where T at boot.jl:396
  Array{Union{Float64, Int64},2}(::UndefInitializer, ::Int64...) where {T, N} at boot.jl:400
  Array{Union{Float64, Int64},2}(::UndefInitializer, ::Integer, ::Integer) where T at sysimg.jl:143
```

Seems like I'm missing and `::UndefInitializer`-type parameter, but what is it exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You spell it as `undef` like this:

```
julia> Array{Union{Int,Float64},2}(undef, 5, 5)
5×5 Array{Union{Float64, Int64},2}:
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
```

You could also write (but this is verbose thus the fist option was introduced):

```
julia> Array{Union{Int,Float64},2}(UndefInitializer(), 5, 5)
5×5 Array{Union{Float64, Int64},2}:
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
```

Comment: Might add that it has nothing to do with the `Union` or anything like that, but is simply how uninitialized arrays in general are constructed in v1.